# Swift realm.io can get object property using object.getValueForKey("key") but not as object.key

Tags: ios, swift, xcode7, realm

I am trying since a whole day migrating my localStorage data to realm.io...
Now the only issue I am facing is that I can get the object property using

```
object.valueforKey("key")
```

but not using the simpler one

```
object.key
```

Here you have a peace of my code

```
        let realm = try! Realm()
        let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "groupID = %@", group.valueForKey("groupID") as! String )
        let current = realm.objects(apiGroup).filter(predicate)
        let currentGroup = current[0]
        print(currentGroup.valueForKey("token") as! String)
        print(currentGroup.token)
```

When I execute that this is been printed on the console.

> 56abbf408cfea7941a8b30b7
>
> ```
> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
> ```

Can you please tell me if this is the normal behaviour or if I can do something to get the

> "object.key"

notation??
Thanks in advance

Comment: Why down vote? let me know as may be an insignificant mistake of me can be the solution

Comment: I upvoted to try and stem the haters. :) The reason being is `object.key` would be in relation to needing an explicitly defined property of the object. Whereas `object.valueForKey()` is a feature of iOS called 'key-value coding' (https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/KeyValueCoding.html) where a specified key may or may not be a value of that object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all for your views. I ended up creating a custom object with a custom init and passing realm object to it...
Then I looped the realm object to assign the same object properties to the custom one... example

```
class Images:Object{
var picid:String = ""
var path:String = ""
var timeStamp:NSDate!
override class func primaryKey() -> String{
    return "picid"
}
}

class realmImages{
var picid:String!
var path:String!
var timeStamp:NSDate!
init(object:Images){
    picid = object.valueForKey("picid") as! String
    path = object.valueForKey("path") as! String
    timeStamp = object.valueForKey("timeStamp") as! NSDate
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hang on! I think I didn't actually understand the question properly!

If the `.token` property is actually a member of your class, that should absolutely work. Just to confirm, are you defining your members of your Realm model subclass properly, according to [the documentation](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/)?

```
class APIGroup: Object {
  dynamic var token = ""
}
```

If so, and you're STILL having trouble, it may be possible that Swift wasn't able to infer that the type of the object returned from the filter wasn't your APIGroup object (Which would explain why `valueForKey` still works).

If that's the case, stating the type should help:

```
let currentGroup = current[0] as APIGroup
```

Let me know if that helped!

Comment: I will check ... Thanks and.. Yes token is a property of apiGroup